# Finding right and left polygons of a given segment

Tags: c#, gis

Polygons are defined by their vertices and sorted CCW, and all polygons are connected.

I need to come up with a way to find for each polygons segment it's right and left polygons (might be only one if its the segment on the outside and no other polygon is connected).

I hope it's clear what's my problem, if not i'll make a picture and upload it to help :)

Comment: Well what's the issue thats stopping you? I really don't think on SO people will be helpful enough to write the code for you.

Comment: I'm looking for a way which takes less than O(n^2), checking each segment with every polygon doesn't seem efficient!

Comment: Are you prepared to use something like dotnettopology suite or postgis? It will make this sort of question a lot easier to solve

Comment: @JohnBarça Thanks for the suggestions, seems good enough to try in future projects, unfortunately there isn't enough time for change with this one.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what tools are available to you, but if you are using ArcGIS you can use the Calculate Adjacent Fields tool located in ArcToolbox > Cartography Tools > Data Driven Pages > Calculate Adjacent Fields.

I have used this tool to calculate adjacent polygons and it appears to do what you need it to do...although you need ArcGIS.

Comment: I need to do that in programmatic way in C#